# Многоразовые внутриигровые покупки

Tags: android, unity3d, in-app-purchases

Делаю игру на Unity. Для совершения покупок внутри игры использую плагин OpenIAB. Подскажите как сделать товар "многоразовым". После первой покупки больше не могу сделать ее снова. Покупается внутриигровая валюта.

UPD:Вроде так и делаю но не выходит

> Нужно "потребить/списать" покупку.

Вот мой код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OnePF;

public class Donat : MonoBehaviour
{

 public const string googlekey =
    "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnEacT+sIFy90sFOY818vKEhuUy4a0rprnr6ZbSIE4cwg+z7ertzatjPJ2olh0TUglCWyDL2MSU0v5BAuLzeuenVxwfBV5qupU54AvZCvThw2LFTZat0vp7o8e3CBL2cpceTBIi6a8fvGxKG7huZjrc9z2waXUskHd7Vgv78kdB1Ea28h2nKSCG/ExubzqRoDU+F53Zp5de6u6Eb8iSWN2jxyHx5GjZnIsGFJKVZOMo+KgMFhoU/f/83rsAbD7heFU4RFqFN7ZXqEMTRct7ZR8JzNppf5GVYfLaT0J1xDX+p2AaDxj4MDObFkSDejTuqMX178zFphBI3ZjccVp4TOTQIDAQAB";

public const string SKU = "korm5k";

private void Awake()
{
    OpenIABEventManager.consumePurchaseSucceededEvent += onConsumePurchaseSucceded;
    OpenIABEventManager.consumePurchaseFailedEvent += onConsumePurchaseFailed;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    OpenIABEventManager.consumePurchaseSucceededEvent -= onConsumePurchaseSucceded;
    OpenIABEventManager.consumePurchaseFailedEvent -= onConsumePurchaseFailed;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    OpenIAB.mapSku(SKU,OpenIAB_Android.STORE_GOOGLE, "korm5k");
    var options = new OnePF.Options();
    options.storeKeys.Add(OpenIAB_Android.STORE_GOOGLE, googlekey);
    OpenIAB.init(options);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void Click()
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case "Buy_Korm5k":
            OpenIAB.purchaseProduct(SKU);
            break;
    }
}

void onConsumePurchaseSucceded(Purchase purchase)
{
    if (purchase.Sku == SKU)
    {
        int s = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
        s += 5000;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score",s);
    }
}

void onConsumePurchaseFailed(string error)
{
    Debug.Log("Ошибка: " + error);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Нужно "потребить/списать" покупку.

[https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Consume](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview#Consume)

```
mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS),
   mConsumeFinishedListener);

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
   new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
   public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
      if (result.isSuccess()) {
         // provision the in-app purchase to the user
         // (for example, credit 50 gold coins to player's character)
      }
      else {
         // handle error
      }
   }
};
```